# PHP : Keeping track of first login and last logout in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing simple sales application where salesman logs in and keeps entering data for all the  meetings/ calls he makes . In my sales person table I've to keep track of  first  and last login of the day , i am really unable to develop any logic for that i mean how can i detect if  this was first login and keep it stored in db and then  last logout of the day , can some one help me with the logic or refer me some links to go through some related stuff

Comment: How about finding a mysql tutorial site.

Comment: This is impressive. I really think you should sit down, take a deep breath and start thinking. How could the first login on a day maybe be identified? Maybe because there is no prior one one the same day that was logged? And how to log the last one? Well, every one is the last one, once you think about it, until another last one is done. So what about storing _every_ login as the last one? Start thinking!

Answer (score 2):

Every login do the following:

- If there is no "first-login value" set for that day in the database, (create it) and set it to that time. also set the "last-login value" to the same time.
- If there is already a "first-login-value" for that day, do not touch it. just set the "last-login value" to the current time.

It can be summarized in the following pseudo-code:

```
// salesman logs in
// check in database first and last login time
if (first-login-time is not set) {
    Now set the first-login-time in the database to the current time
}

// you always need to do this
Now set the last-login-time in the database
```

At the end of the day, you'll either have no values (no login). Both values to the same time (one login). Or two different values, which will be the first and last login time.